# Energy-Casimir method

Tags: control-theory, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

In the Energy-Casimir method, it is said we look for 'conserved quantities' that are a function of the system. Then subsequently $V = \mathcal{H} + \mathcal{C}$ becomes the candidate Lyapunov function, in which $\mathcal{H}$ is the Hamiltonian and $\mathcal{C}$ is the Casimir function.

But how does it make sense that you see $\dot{\mathcal{C}}=0$ in books? It seems that if $\mathcal{C}$ remains constant that this will not move the coordinates of the minimum of $V$ at all. But moving it is what you want to get stability (proof) at a certain (equilibrium) point of the system.

Can anybody explain this?

Comment: Can you give references to this Energy-Casimir method? How does the Casimir function look like?

Comment: Energy-Casimir method: page 14/15, http://www.math.rug.nl/arjan/DownloadPublicaties/ICMvanderSchaft.pdf . The actual casimir function is different for each system.

Comment: Also: https://www.rug.nl/research/portal/files/14403036/2001IEEEContSystMagOrtega.pdf (page24/25/26)